# Thunderbolt Monitor Issue 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, thunderbolt

I have two external monitors attached to my laptop, which is an ASUS Tuf Gaming laptop. The two monitors are 27" Asus. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, with Linux 5.17.4-051704. I have a Thunderbolt 4 port and an HDMI port I am trying to take advantage of. I am able to plug either monitor into the HDMI port to get it working. I tried using an HDMI splitter but neither monitor works when both are connected. Right now I have one monitor plugged into the HDMI port and another into the Thunderbolt port. Only the HDMI monitor works. I also bought an Thunderbolt splitter and neither works when I use that. If I try a monitor only in the Thunderbolt port it doesn't work. I'm at a loss here.